# correct way to call GraphQL mutation from react using hooks

Tags: reactjs, graphql, mutation

I have defined the following mutation and inputtype:

```
extend type Mutation {

    signup(input: SignupReq!): SignupStatus!

}

input SignupReq {
    email: String!
    password: String!
}
```

using graphql playground:

```
mutation signup{signup(input:{password:"blabla", email: "my@email.dk"}){success, message}}
```

it returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "signup": {
      "success": true,
      "message": "Success!"
    }
  }
}
```

which is what I expect.

but how do I call this mutation from my React client?

what I have now is:

```
const SIGNUP_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation SignupUser($input: SignupReq!) {
    signup(signupReq: $input) {success, message, token}
  }
`

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')


const [signup, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(SIGNUP_MUTATION)


const { data, loading, error } = await signup({ variables: { email, password } })
```

which is pretty much standard.

but I'm missing something I just cant pinpoint. Cause running the React script gives me the following error message:

```
'Field "signup" argument "input" of type "SignupReq!" is required, but it was not provided.',
```

How do I make the correct call to Graphql from react. I have been unable to find any documentation on how to use input types for mutations from React.

any help welcome.

Kim

Comment: read about passing variables ... use variables in graphiql/playground ... code later

Comment: https://graphqlmastery.com/blog/graphql-quick-tip-how-to-pass-variables-in-graphiql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in `email` and `password` as variables into your mutation:

```js
variables: { email, password }
```

Instead, as you can see from your mutation, you have to pass in an `input` variable:

```js
variables: {
  input: {
    email,
    password
  }
}
```

This will work, as it then mirrors the type used in your GraphQL schema:

```
input SignupReq {
  email: String!
  password: String!
}
```